# TSQL How to convert varchar to numeric on a Case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here's my query.  I want to take the [Market Value] Case expression and add it to the 'Certified' Case expression.

```
  DECLARE @AS_OF_DATE DATE
SET @AS_OF_DATE = '01/27/2016'

SELECT
    'AS OF DATE'    = @AS_OF_DATE   
,   A.AcctNbr
,   A.CUSIPNumber
,   B.Desc1
,   B.Symbol
,   'SEC TYPE'  = RTRIM (B.SecType)+B.CmpQual+B.SecQual
,   A.AcctType
,   A.LocMemo
,   A.BegSdQuantity
,   B.ClosePrice
,   [MARKET VALUE]  = (CASE WHEN RTRIM (B.SECTYPE)+B.CmpQual+B.SecQual IN ('A01', 'A02', 'B01', 'B02', 'C01', 'C02', 'F01', 'F02', 'F03',
    'F04', 'F05', 'F06', 'G01', 'G02', 'G03', 'G04', 'H01', 'H02', 'T01', '501', '502', '503', '504', '601', '602', '603')
    THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(25,3),A.BegSdQuantity * B.ClosePrice)
    ELSE CONVERT(DECIMAL(25,3),A.BegSdQuantity /100 * B.ClosePrice) END)
,   'TOTAL DEBIT'   = C.SETTLEBalance
,   'HYPOTHECATION' = C.SETTLEBalance * 1.40
,   'CERTIFIED'     =  (CASE WHEN ((('MARKET VALUE') < (C.SETTLEBalance * 1.40)) OR
                        (C.SETTLEBalance * 1.40 = '0.00')) THEN 'CERTIFIED'
                        ELSE 'EXCEPTION'
                        END)

FROM vw_Table A
INNER join vw_Table B on A.FirmCUSIPId = B.FirmCUSIPId
    AND @AS_OF_DATE between a.EffectiveDate and a.ExpirationDate
    AND @AS_OF_DATE between b.EffectiveDate and b.ExpirationDate
INNER JOIN vw_Table C ON A.FirmAccountId = C.FirmAccountId
    AND @AS_OF_DATE BETWEEN C.EffectiveDate AND C.ExpirationDate
```

When run this query above I get the error message:  "Error converting data type varchar to numeric"

Any thought on how I can fix this?

Thanks,

Comment: You have `'MARKET VALUE'` which is `varchar` compared with numbers

Comment: `C.SETTLEBalance * 1.40 = '0.00'`? Without the schemas this is question is impossible to interpret.

Comment: I'm not sure why I get a down vote for asking a question.  Not everyone here are experts.  Please don't think everyone asking questions knows how to query or even how the SQL is suppose to work.  I try to add as much content to the question as possible without giving away the security of my company.  I figured this out using CTE's and I'll post my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here

```
CASE WHEN ((('MARKET VALUE') < (C.SETTLEBalance * 1.40))
```

You are comparing the varchar value *"MARKET VALUE"* against a numeric value. what do you expect?

Might be, that you should put the closing paranthesis right behind "A.BegSdQuantity", don't know what data types are there...:

```
CONVERT(DECIMAL(25,3),A.BegSdQuantity) * B.ClosePrice
```

But without any knowledge of your table's declarations this is reading a magic glass bulb...